# Where did expiring S3 URLs go in the AWS console?

Tags: amazon-s3

I used to be able to create expiring (signed) URLs directly from within AWS console very easily, just right-click the item, choose web URL, and voila.

This feature seems to have disappeared sometime this year.  Does anyone know how to do it now?  I am not looking for a programmatic solution, I just occasionally need to whip up an expiring URL for a file, about once or twice a year.  I really don't want to bother with a third party tool either, I want to know how one does it from within AWS console now, in 2015.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This option was never available in the AWS Management Console.

If you use `Actions -> Open` on the file from within the Console it generates a signed URL, but there is no capability to edit the parameters.

It is, however, available in:

- The [AWS Toolkit for Visual Studio](https://aws.amazon.com/visualstudio/)
- [Cloudberry Explorer PowerShell](http://www.cloudberrylab.com/blog/how-to-create-signed-urls-with-powershell-and-cloudberry-s3-explorer/)
- [Bucket Explorer](http://www.bucketexplorer.com/)
- [GitHub amazon-s3-url-signer](https://github.com/dyashkir/amazon-s3-url-signer)
- [GitHub s3-signed-url](https://github.com/rbrigham/s3-signed-url)
- Your own code! [Signing Amazon S3 URLs](https://coderwall.com/p/mtcskq/signing-amazon-s3-urls)

Comment: Maybe I was using some other tool, could've sworn it was the AWS console.

Comment: in case it helps any other Mac users, I ended up using a third party tool after all, www.dragondisk.com - it's no longer being developed but it's working great for me and is free.